# Convertir pdf en byte[] y viceversa ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo que guardar un PDF en un campo de una tabla en SQL Server 2016.

Informándome he visto que la mejor forma de hacerlo es convirtiéndolo en byte[].
El problema es que no termino de dar con un método que me sirva, puesto que lo quiero hacer de la siguiente manera:

Cuando creo un nuevo registro, desde la vista Create, tengo un campo que es para seleccionar el fichero de mi equipo que quiero guardar en la BBDD.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Compras</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">

    </div>        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empresaC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.empresaC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empresaC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.num_diarC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.num_diarC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.num_diarC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.num_movC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.num_movC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.num_movC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mes_diarC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mes_diarC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mes_diarC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.anno_diarC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.anno_diarC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.anno_diarC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.codigoC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.codigoC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.codigoC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombreC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombreC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombreC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.num_factC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.num_factC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.num_factC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fec_factC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fec_factC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fec_factC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imp_factC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.imp_factC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imp_factC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tiva_factC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tiva_factC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tiva_factC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.kg_facC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.kg_facC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.kg_facC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.obs_factC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.obs_factC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.obs_factC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imagenC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4 btn">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imagenC, new { type="file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imagenC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Añadir" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Lo que quiero es saber cómo puedo convertir el fichero en byte[] al seleccionarlo en la vista Create. Y después como volverlo a convertir (sin tener que descargarlo) para visualizarlo en la vista Details.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <section>
        <iframe src="~/src/donquijote1.pdf" style="width:650px; height:700px;" frameborder="0" />
    </section>
</div>
```

Sentencia Create:

```
            [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idC,empresaC,num_diarC,num_movC,mes_diarC,anno_diarC,codigoC,nombreC,num_factC,fec_factC,imp_factC,tiva_factC,kg_facC,obs_factC,id_imagenC,imagenC")] ModelCompra compra)
    {
        Compra dbCompra = new Compra();

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
            dbCompra = new ModelCompra().getDbCompra(compra);
            db.Compras.Add(dbCompra);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (DbEntityValidationResult item in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    // Get entry

                    DbEntityEntry entry = item.Entry;
                    string entityTypeName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;

                    // Display or log error messages

                    foreach (DbValidationError subItem in item.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("Error '{0}' occurred in {1} at {2}",
                                 subItem.ErrorMessage, entityTypeName, subItem.PropertyName);
                    throw new DbEntityValidationException(message);
                }
            }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    return View(compra);
    }
```

El try/catch está porque tuve otro problema y necesitaba ampliar el informe de errores

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que se ejecuta cuando envías el formulario? La conversión debe ocurrir ahí.

Comment: Abres el pdf de una carpeta?

Comment: Ya lo he añadido, estoy perdidísimo.
@Rastalovely Si, el archivo se seleccionaría de una carpeta local. He pensado en guardarlo temporalmente, convertirlo, guardar el byte[] y después borrar el fichero temporal. Aún así necesitaría orientación.

Answer (score 3):

Para convertir un archivo PDF en bytes podes usar lo siguiente

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Archivo.pdf");
```

Y para convertir los bytes de nuevo a PDF

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Archivo.pdf", bytes);
```